# Command error makemigrations in a Python/Django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Python: `2.7`

Django: `1.6`

I'm using `virtualenv` to manage my projects.

I have my app added to INSTALLED_APPS.

Tried to run the following command:

```
(pythonenv-1.6)xxxxx@xxxx.com
python manage.py makemigrations
Unknown command: 'makemigrations'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I've tried the `python manage.py makemigrations my_app_name` and didn't work too. :(

Comment: until django 1.7 migration was managed by south. It did not come inbuilt. Please check that.

Comment: If you're using Django 1.6 - it didn't have native migrations until 1.7/1.8... Prior to that it was a 3rd party add-on called "south"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says that command is unknown. It was surely added in a later django version. If you don't like south you can drop table and run syncdb or manually change the SQL with ALTER command.

Comment: How do I use `makemigrations` in South?

Comment: I saw in the South documentation. Thank you anyway. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry I am not a big fan of south, I always used SQL commands migrations with older django versions. I am happy you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ninja Puppy comment, here's a formal answer for future reference:

Django 1.6 relies on 3rd party add-on "South" and therefore we have to use this for initialising

```
./manage.py my_app_name southtut --initial
```

and then this for updating changes

```
./manage.py my_app_name southtut --auto
```

instead of

```
python manage.py makemigrations my_app_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have a nice day.